# Custom broadcast connection\driver?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Recently I've been trying to implement bidirectional realtime communication in my app, I've tried many things like "pusher", what's so called pusher replacement `beyondcode\laravel-websockets`, "socket.io" and all the things you come into when researching websockets and realtime communication, however, it was difficult for me to use any of these options to achieve "bi-directionality" so I switched to a totally custom implementation (well.. not totally) where I use `cboden/ratchet` as a websocket server together with custom very simple front-end\client javascript code.

Now (naturally) broadcasting events like so `event(new SomeEvent($data))` doesn't work anymore and I believe to get it back to work again I need to write my own broadcasting "driver \ connection" and my problem is that I don't know how to go about that and where to start, it's a whole new level for me :| so if any of you guys can be of any help it would be great! and thanks anyway!